# Stuck while generating sitemap with google chrome extension Sitemap Generator

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, sitemap

I am trying to generate a sitemap for my react js website using Sitemap Generator extension of googlechrome. (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sitemap-generator/hcnjemngcihnhncobgdgkkfkhmleapah?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). It says it works with reactjs applications. But in my case it doesnt move beyond the base URL. I tried with multiple extensions same behavior is seen with them as well. Check the image below where it shows its stuck on the base link.

[Sitemap generator Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKl8x.png)

Any idea why this might be happening.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening because I was saving my access_token in localStorage and all the pages were protected. The crawler was not able to access the token and therefore was not able to crawl through the other pages. I solved this by storing the token in redux store. So that it would be available to the crawler as well.

This is a solution I could think of. Please in case you have a better solution to this please let it be known here :) Especially if the project doesn't have redux store how would we solve this. Thank you.